# Does NEFilterProvider requires supervised iOS devices for debugging also?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have found that NEFilterProvider runs only on supervised devices. But i want to know here that do we need the supervised devices for debugging purpose also? or we can debug the NEFilterProvider on normal devices?
Thanks 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nefilterprovider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development builds can be run and debugged on non-supervised devices (assuming of course they have the necessary `com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension` entitlements).

Remember to attach to the extension to use breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.I am not able to trigger the breakpoints even after attaching to the extensions. Can you please help me out by providing some more information to use the breakpoints?